# posting data-attr value to php using ajax post empty data

Tags: php, ajax

I was working on `WAMP` localhost server and tried below `ajax` code and posted data, after testing i hosted on webserver, while testing i noticed `ajax` send empty post.

**code**

```
         $(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.trash', function () {
                var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: {'del_id': del_id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data === "YES") {
                            $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                        } else {
                            alert("can't delete the row")
                        }
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="hello" class="trash" >button</a>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
//echo $music_number;

if(isset($music_number)) {
   echo "YES";
} else {
   echo "NO";
}
```

> Why do ajax send empty post data - if script is wrong it should have shown in localhost.
>   what should i do to sove this problem (do i need to configure in webserver).

her is hosted demo https://sanojword.000webhostapp.com/dashboard/testindex

Comment: The problem that you are experiencing is somewhere on your server you are redirecting `test.php` to `test`. But in your ajax you are referring to `test.php` instead of using `test` as the URL.

Comment: @imvain2 the reason in i used `.htaccess` to hide file extension will it cause `ajax` problem, `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: You need to refer to the URL that is being redirected to not redirected from. Since you are redirecting `test.php` to `test`, that redirect is happening in your ajax.

So in your ajax change `test.php` to `test`.

Comment: it worker now, thats the reason it worker on localhost,